# Scraping Wikipedia tables whith cells spanning multiple rows

Tags: r, web-scraping, html-table, rvest

I'm trying to scrape information from Wikipedia tables using html_table from the rvest package. However, when inspecting the tables afterwards, the colums are misaligned because the original tables have cells spanning multiple rows. I know the vignette for html_table says that the function assumes that tables don't contain cells spanning multiple rows, so I wanted to ask for alternatives?

htmltable doesn't really work for me because I'm scraping a lot of tables in a loop and they aren't all the same length, so the function cannot really deal with that (and returns the error: numbr of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length). Is there any possibility to maybe solve the misalignment problem after I downloaded the tables with html_table?

some reproducible code:

```
musicians <- c("Bob Dylan", "John Lennon")

link <- character()
for(j in seq_along(musicians)){
  link[j] <- paste0('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/', 
                   musicians[j], ' discography')
}
```

with htmltab it doesn't work and I'm guessing it's because the tables have different lengths?

```
info <- list()
for(p in seq_along(link)){
  info[p <- htmltab(wik[p], which = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[2]') 
}
```

and with read_html the tables being downloaded are misaligned (the order of the colums doesn't fit anymore)

```
for(k in seq_along(link)){
info[k] <- read_html(link[k]) %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[2]') %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE, header = FALSE)
}
```

Does anybody know any solution to these problems? I'd be glad if just one of these worked out somehow, even if just finding an automated way to edit the misaligned colums after downloading them (without having to look up where the colums don't fit in every single data frame), because at the moment I don't really have an idea how to move on from here.

**EDIT:** **I found a solution** for my own problem today and wanted to share it in case somebody else is also facing the same struggles I did with the misaligned colums in an html table.
There's a function called xml_remove which can exclude the annoying nodes that are causing the misalignment problems.

example code using the xpaths of the nodes belonging to the tables mentioned above:

```
url <- read_html(url)

xml_remove(html_nodes(url,
                      xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/th[4]'))

tab <- html_nodes(url, xpath = '//*[@id="mw-content-text"]/div/table[2]') %>% 
  html_table(fill = TRUE)
```